# UNIX command find starting directory .*

Tags: unix, find

Can you explain what does the following UNIX command find does?

```
find .*
```

where .* - starting directory.

I know "." is current directory, but cannot find the explanation about ".*".

Comment: `.*` is a wildcard, "anything that starts with a dot". What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I just wondered, what this command does, since I didn't find any examples of it. So that seems I have understood now. The command just finds all items inside the directories (of the current directory) that start with ".". Isn't it?

Comment: No. This command does nothing, it is wrong, as it is telling you. Read `man find`, there *are* examples. In short, the first (mandatory) argument must be existing *starting directory*, under which hierarchy it will search for objects, filtered by options *following* it.

Comment: But this command outputs the list with results.

Comment: You said there is no examples, — I've told you where to look for examples (it turned out an official application manual page has them). You asked what the command does, — the application told you it is wrong, does nothing, and I explained why. *You* might be able to have a reasonable meaning for this command, but the `find` application doesn't understand it. Just bear with it, it is how it is written and complaints won't change it. The best approach to list everything starting with a dot using `find` would be `find . -name '*.'`, if that's what you need, but you never said you need that.